# overwrite window.open properties in opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent page which has a link which opens a new pop-up window with-out scroll.
the code is being used in parent windiow is:

```
ebayShowPopupWindow(this.href, '', 472, 320, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no');
```

And method implmentation is:

```
function showPopupWindow(url, name, width, height, toolbar, location, status, scrollbars, resizable, menubar, left, top, customprops) {
    var props = "";
    if (width) props += ",width=" + width;
    if (height) props += ",height=" + height;
    if (toolbar) props += ",toolbar=" + toolbar;
    if (location) props += ",location=" + location;
    if (status) props += ",status=" + status;
    if (scrollbars) props += ",scrollbars=" + scrollbars;
    if (resizable) props += ",resizable=" + resizable;
    if (menubar) props += ",menubar=" + menubar;
    if (left) props += ",screenX=" + left + ",left=" + left;
    if (top) props += ",screenY=" + top + ",top=" + top;
    if (customprops) props += "," + customprops;
    if (props != "") props = props.substring(1);
    var w = window.open(url, name, props);
    if (!is.opera && w && !w.closed) w.focus();
    return w;
}
```

Now my question is: Can we overwrite window scroll property in the child window's page-load?

Reason for this:  We have a page link being used by different teams and they restrict the scroll in the pop-window which hides some part of the page.

I was trying to some thing like this that did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = $.browser;
    window.scrollbars = 'yes';
    window.scrollbars.visible= true;
});
```